# pyspark python dataframe reuse in different functions

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

**Problem**

I have a pyspark job file in which certain dataframe is read from parquet file and some filtered are applied. these operations are common and i want them to be done only once. but i dont know that how can i pass the huge dataframe in function or correctly store it as global variable.

**What i tried**:

I have three option in mind. ut not sure if they are efficent or not

1. Pass this dataframe to each function
2. Define this dataframe as empty in main and access/modify it in other functions(not sure as it `gives reference errors`).
3. `Persist/Cache` dataframe till these steps

**Code:**

```
def function1():
       df_in_concern = sqlContext.read.parquet(...)
       df_in_concern = df_in_concern.filter(...)
       df_in_concern = df_in_concern.filter(...)

def function2():
       df_in_concern = sqlContext.read.parquet(...)
       df_in_concern = df_in_concern.filter(...)
       df_in_concern = df_in_concern.filter(...)

def main():
     function1()
     function2()


if __name__ == "__main__":

    main()
```

So, if there is some way to commonly access the `df_in_concern`, it will avoid the heavy joins and reads again and again in different functions

Comment: consider `registerTempTable`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`spark_dataframe.createOrReplaceTempView("tmp_table_name")` is probably your best option, use as following:

```py
def read_table_first_time():
    df1 = spark.createDataFrame([("val",)],["key"])
    df1.createOrReplaceTempView("df1")

def read_table_again():
    df_ref = spark.table("df1")
    df_ref.show()

read_table_first_time()
read_table_again()
```

this outputs

```
+---+
|key|
+---+
|val|
+---+
```

Comment: thanks for answer, will i doubt that i will be able to access it in non-sql way(filter() join () etc).  If not, is it the only way?

Comment: well you can do `registerTempTable` AFTER your filter operations

Comment: I believe you will need to put `spark.cacheTable("df1")` , otherwise it will be same as accessing again and again?

Comment: I was thinking that `registerTempTable` keeps it in memory - let me double-check.

Comment: I can save it after filter but i will need it as DF to perform further actions in each function, can you please also write to convert it back to DF.

Comment: yeah `registerTempTable() creates an in-memory table that is scoped to the cluster` ... so there's no disk i/o.

https://forums.databricks.com/questions/400/what-is-the-difference-between-registertemptable-a.html

Comment: note that `registerTempTable()` is deprecated starting Spark 2.0, use `createOrReplaceTempView` is what the documentation says.

Comment: Thanks!!! I was not aware - and that's something I should definitely know! yes - please use `createOrReplaceTempView` instead - should behave the same! -- I'll update the answer for others who might read it in the future!

Comment: Hi @avloss, Want to reuse code (set of rules) so I used udf (instead of 'case when' and otherwise on df) but what I observed is code with udf runs slow when data is around 100million records.

What will be you suggestions on this as want to reuse implemented rules.