# How to pass dataframe to different functions with filters and group by

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a dataframe from a query in pyspark. But I want to pass the dataframe to 2 different functions in pyspark.

Basically, I am doing something like this, and would like to avoid running the same query to create `initial_df` twice.

```
def post_process_1(df):
       df = df_in_concern.filter(1st set of filter and group by)
       write_to_table_1(df)

def post_process_2(df):
       df = df_in_concern.filter(2nd set of filter and group by)
       write_to_table_2(df)

initial_df = df.filter(...).groupby(...).order1(...)
post_process_1(initial_df)
post_process_2(initial_df)
```

I found this post  which talks about a problem similar to mine.
[pyspark python dataframe reuse in different functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55870621/pyspark-python-dataframe-reuse-in-different-functions)

And, the suggestion is to use `createOrReplaceTempView`. But from what I learn, this function `createOrReplaceTempView` needs the query to be using `SQL` syntax.

And in my example, `post_process_1`, `post_process_2`, the query (filter/ group by) are done using pyspark.

Is there any way I can avoid querying `initial_df` twice and keep using pyspark queries (not sql queries) in my `post_process_1`, `post_process_2` functions?

Comment: if `initial_df` is small enough to fit in memory, you can choose to `persist()` it before passing it to your functions. [read more on this](https://sparkbyexamples.com/spark/spark-dataframe-cache-and-persist-explained/)

Comment: Thanks. How can i tell if it is small enough to fit in memory?

Comment: Your functions do not modify `df`.  Why do you think there is a problem?

Comment: You can `persist()` a dataframe even if it is not small. What you might find though is that letting catalyst optimizer deal with/combine filters applied in `initial_df` and each of the functions could be more beneficial than you think.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do the work since df is being filtered in the context of the method only and it is not changing anything on initial_df:

```py
def post_process_1(df):
    df_ = df.filter(1st set of filter and group by)
    write_to_table_1(df_)

def post_process_2(df):
    df_ = df.filter(2nd set of filter and group by)
    write_to_table_2(df_)

initial_df = df.filter(...).groupby(...).order1(...)
post_process_1(initial_df)
post_process_2(initial_df)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use **persist/cache** (with the required storage levels as required if using cache). This is to prevent recomputing of the initial_df

```
def post_process_1(df):
      df = df_in_concern.filter(1st set of filter and group by)
      write_to_table_1(df)

def post_process_2(df):
      df = df_in_concern.filter(2nd set of filter and group by)
      write_to_table_2(df)

initial_df = df.filter(...).groupby(...).order1(...)
initial_df.persist()
post_process_1(initial_df)
post_process_2(initial_df)
```